# React native section list not re-rendering when item changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have a sectionList in my react native project. it does not re-render if item changes.
My code:

test.js

```
class Test extends React.Component {
started = false;
causeData=[];
showLess=false;
items = [];

_start = () => {
    const { ws } = this.props;

    this.showLess = false;
    if (ws.causes.length) {
  this.causeData = {
    title: Language.causes,
    key: "cause",
    data: []
  };

  ws.causes.forEach(cause => {
    let causeDetails = {
      key: "cause_" + cause.id,
      name: "",
      value: cause.name,
      sortIndex: cause.sortIndex,
      progress: cause.progress
    };
    this.causeData.data.push(causeDetails);

    if (this.causeData.data.length > 4) {
      this.causeData.data = this.causeData.data.slice(0, 4);
    }
  });
  this.items.push(this.causeData);
  console.log("causeData", this.causeData);
  }  
  }
  }

 _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
     return (
          <View>
          <Text key={item.key} style={styles.text}>{`${item.name}  ${
            item.value
          }`}</Text>
        </View>
  );
 };

_renderSectionHeader = ({ section }) => {
   const { ws } = this.props;
   const showMore = ws.causes.length > 0 && !this.showLess;

  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
      <Text key={section.key} style={styles.header}>
        {section.title}
      </Text>
      {showMore && (
        <Button
          onPress={this._afterCauseAnswered}
          title={Language.showMore}
          data={this.items}
          accessibilityLabel={Language.causeDoneAccessibility}
        />
      )}
      </View>
    );
    };

   _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.key;

  _afterCauseAnswered = () => {

    const { stepDone, ws } = this.props;
    this.causeData.data = { ...ws.causes };

    stepDone("showMoreAnswered");
    this.showLess = true;
  };

  render = () => {
  if (!this.started) {
  this.started = true;
  this._start();
  }
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SectionList
      sections={this.items}
      extraData={this.items}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    />
  </View>
);
};
}
```

in my section list section header contain a button called showMore. At initial rendering it will only show 5 items, while clicking showMore it should display all List. This is my functionality. but while clicking showMore button it will not show entire list only shows 5 items that means the sectionList does not getting re-render. How to resolve this? i am new to react native. Any idea what am I missing ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Keep `items` and `showLess` in a state and after pressing Button call `setState` with the new values. It will rerender the `SectionList`. Also, if you want to display multiple items with a displayed list, you need to move `showLess` to the item element so each item knows how to display it.

Comment: actually am not using setState am using redux in my project.  "ws.cause" is from redux state. so how to solve this

Comment: You can call `this.forceUpdate()` but this is not a good approach. You need to pass changed items to `SectionList` as `sections` or `extraData` directly from the props. In your case, you are changing items but since `SectionList`'s `sections` value is not coming from `this.state` or `this.props` it should not update the `SectionList`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rerender your screen using state and it's done

```
this.setState({})
```

Comment: what if data is coming from prop ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SectionList` should always read from `state` ... as it should be your **single source of truth**

and here's how:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
  };

  // This will be called after your action is executed,
  // and your component is about to receive a new set of causes...
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
      ws: { causes: nextCauses },
    } = nextProps;
    if (newCauses) {
      // let items = ...
      // update yout items here
      this.setState({ items });
    }
  }
}
```